# Sphinx - Using the search page

Tags: python-sphinx

I have created a new sphinx documentation. I've come across a bit of an issue with the search function. When I use the quick search or the search page, it seems like its doing something, but it never actually finishes the search. I've had it going for an hour now and it's still searching.

I only have 3 .rst files in the documentation so far so I was wondering why it's taking so long to search and if anyone has come across this before?

Thanks

[EDIT 1: Developer tools image, showing what happens when I use the search page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SyIJ.png)

Comment: Open up your browser's developer tools, and see if any requests fail. This sounds like a JavaScript does not load.

Comment: Do you have a script blocking extension?

Comment: I've added an image into the main question to show what happens in the developer tools.

Comment: Have you tried with a different browser? The error seems very specific to chrome (well, that is what I find on google).

Comment: Tried it with Safari. It just takes hours to search so I just turn it off in the end.

Comment: If you want further help, I believe you should provide a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)

Comment: I've fixed my issue, thanks anyway. It didn't have a documentation_options.js file so I made one and voila!